# Shortcut to clear annotations in Sublime JsHint

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, jshint

I know that the first key is command, but what is the 2nd key?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's the escape key, so push cmd + esc